# How to customize JMeter Dashboard Report generated in Jmeter v3.1?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

the requirement is to display the timezone for test execution in PST and change the error label KO to something like Failure. Can anyone please let me know how to achieve the same when creating Jmeter dashboard report.

Answer (score 1):

1. To change `KO` label:

   - Locate `ApacheJMeter_core.jar` file under "lib/ext" folder of your JMeter installation
   - Open it (as normal ZIP archive)
   - Go to `org/apache/jmeter/resources/message.properties`
   - Locate the following line:

     ```
     reportgenerator_summary_statistics_error_count=KO
     ```
   - change this `OK` to whatever you like
2. To change timezone just change your machine timezone, JMeter will respect it. You might also find the following properties which live in the `reportgenerator.properties` file (located in JMeter's "bin" folder) useful:

   ```
   jmeter.reportgenerator.start_date=
   jmeter.reportgenerator.end_date=
   ```

References:

- [Configuring Dashboard Generation](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html#configuration)
- [Configuring JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)

Comment: I tried the above mentioned steps and was able to change 'KO' appearing in Statistics Table column header, but could not change the 'KO'appearing in PIE Chart. Any idea how to change the 'KO' to 'Failed' appearing in PIE Chart.

Answer (score 1):

@VishvaPradeep To change KO in Pie Chart. Just go to `Jmeter\bin\report-template\content\js\dashboard.js.fmkr`

Search "KO"

Search Result will be this:

```
 {
            "label" : "KO",
            "data" : data.KoPercent,
            "color" : "#FF6347"
 }
```

and Update "KO" with "Failed". From now on it will create new report as "Failed" label in Pie Chart.

For Existing Report, Go to same path and edit `dashboard.js` and change "KO" to "Failed".