# Jmeter Dashboard report - how to change 'KO' to 'FAILED' in Pie chart of Summary Report

Tags: jmeter

Requirement is to change the 'KO'to 'FAILED' appearing in Request Summary PIE CHART of  Jmeter Dashboard report.

I made the changes as described in the following link. Was able to change 'KO' in Statistics Table column header, but is still reflecting 'KO' in PIE CHART.

Could any one please guide me how to change 'KO' to 'FAILED' in Jmeter Dashboard Request Summary PIE CHART.

[How to customize JMeter Dashboard Report generated in Jmeter v3.1?](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/26689/how-to-customize-jmeter-dashboard-report-generated-in-jmeter-v3-1)

Comment: I tried the samething to change the KO to Failed but it didnot work for me and also I have another question for you, Instead of visualising the pass and failure % of the test suite in the pie chart, Can we visualise the number of the tests passed and failed in the pie chart? var data = ${requestsSummary!"{}"}; var dataset = [ { "label" : "FAILED", "data" : data.KoPercent, "color" : "#FF6347" }, { "label" : "OK", "data" : data.OkPercent, "color" : "#9ACD32" }]; [![pie chart results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbQzZ.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbQzZ.png)

Answer (score 2):

Apart from changing `reportgenerator_summary_statistics_error_count` property value to `FAILED` you need to do the following:

1. Locate the following line in the `report-template\content\js\dashboard.js.fmkr` file

   ```
   var dataset = [
       {
           "label" : "KO",
           "data" : data.KoPercent,
           "color" : "#FF6347"
       },
       {
           "label" : "OK",
           "data" : data.OkPercent,
           "color" : "#9ACD32"
       }];
   ```
2. Change `"label" : "KO"` to `"label" : "FAILURES`
3. Re-generate your JMeter dashboard

References:

- [Configuring JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)
- [Generating Report Dashboard](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html)

Comment: Thank you so much Dmitri. was able to change the 'KO' in Pie Chart of Summary request to 'FAILURES'